# Get embedded values in javascript function on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using php and trying to fetch a value in a javascript function. 
The javascript in the HTML page is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function show(q)
        {
            if(q.length > 0)
            {           
                if(q.indexOf("tid") > -1)
                {
                    location.href = "map.jsp?" + q;
                }
                else
                {
                    location.href = "listmap.jsp?" + q;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        $(function() { 
            $("#map").goMap({ 
                latitude: -35.331415
                ,longitude: 149.131851
                ,maptype: 'ROADMAP'
                ,scrollwheel: false
                ,zoom: 11
                ,markers: [ {latitude: -35.192103,longitude: 149.332313,icon: 'images/m/marker1.png',html: {content: 'Loading...', ajax: 'mapinfo.jsp?sid=9057'}}]
```

I need to get the values of (3rd and 4th lines in second function) the latitude and longitude which are: -35.331415 and 149.131851

I'm just not sure how to access the individual values...

EDIT: I AM USING PHP to save these values in variables then later write them to a csv file
Currently i'm using this code (here's a snippit) to get everything else on other pages

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init("http://pvoutput.org/listmap.jsp?sid=312");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom ->loadHTML($cl);

$Lat_data = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("script");
print_r($Lat_data -> item(1) );
```

EDIT 2: 
I fixed all the problems by doing this:

```
$Lat_data = $dom -> getElementsByTagName("script");
$content =$Lat_data -> item(10) -> textContent;

$regex = "/latitude: ([^\b,]*)/"; 
if (preg_match( $regex , $content , $values )) {
echo  $values[1];
$regex2 = "/longitude: ([^\b,]*)/";
}
if (preg_match($regex2, $content, $values2)) {
echo $values2[1];
}
```

Comment: I think we need more context here. Where are you trying to access these values?

Comment: EDIT attached, please check the discription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You managed to get the script node. Now you want its content (the javascript code)

```
$content = $Lat_data -> item(1) -> textContent
```

Once you got the content you can parse it using regex expression to get what you want

```
$regex = "/latitude: ([^\b\n]*)(.|\n)*,longitude: ([^\b\n,]*)/";
if (preg_match($regex, $content, $values)) {
   echo 'latitude: ' . $values[0];
   echo 'longitue: ' . $values[2];
}
```

regex explanation (test [here](http://regex101.com/r/hB8bW6/2)):

- finds "latitude: "
- then we get the first group (), [^\b\n]* means anything but blackspace or newline characters
- get anything between latitude value and ',longitude: '
- next find ",longitude: "
- third group just as the previous one. I added ',' so that if there is not blank between the longitude and ', maptype' it still works.

this regex explanation is getting a little messy, check the test link to more detailed explanation.

I have not tested it so there might be some syntax error but the idea is there ;)

Comment: You are awesome. 
But I get syntax error, unexpected / (before the latitude in the $regex = /latitude

Comment: @AhmadK try replacing / by ". Also I corrected the regex

Comment: Added newlines detection. I thought \b included newlines but that is not the case

Comment: Thanks soooo much! 

There was a small mistake there, instead of using "ereg" we should use "preg_match" otherwise we will get "Function ereg() is deprecated"

Also I separated what you wrote into two separate parts to get the two values individually, as so: 
    
    $regex = "/latitude: ([^\b,]*)/";
    
    if (preg_match( $regex , $content , $values )) {
 echo  $values[1];
    $regex2 = "/longitude: ([^\b,]*)/";
    }
    if (preg_match($regex2, $content, $values2)) {
 echo $values2[1];

    }

Comment: Getting both values separately makes it easier. I edited answer to use __preg_match__ as you suggested.

Comment: I've been playing around with that regex. I finaly found a much smarter [regex expression](http://regex101.com/r/hB8bW6/4):
**/latitude: (\S*).*,longitude: (\S*)/s**

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be more efficient to implement a bit of ajax to submit the Longitude and Latitude from your js file to your php file?

Comment: This is not my javascript code, I'm just accessing it using php and Curl Handler. I just want to snatch the values written in the HTML code :)